# How to Disable/Enable JFrame Component when JInternalFrame isVisible inside JFrame/JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visible, jinternalframe

How to Disable/Enable `JFrame` components when `JInternalFrame` isVisible inside `JFrame`/`JDesktopPane`? For example, make every `JInternalFrame1` visible on the `JDesktopPane` (desktop pane set on the `JFrame`) all frame components like `JMenuBar`/`JButton`/etc. set disabled.

Have a solution?

Comment: @AJ but that will make all the panel "disappear" not become disabled.

Comment: @prmottajr you're right, I mean the component just disable not dispose :)

Comment: I try create 'that' JInternalFrame inside JFrame, but a hundred error message show when I run the program.

Comment: What I've done in the past is used `JXLayer`/`JLayer` wrapped it around the `JRootPane` and installed a "disabled" layer onto it.  This has the nice effect of disabling the menus, the content pane and if I recall correctly, the glass pane as well.  You can set this to the main frame as well as the internal frames as needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you share example code how to make it work?

Comment: Updated with JXLayer example

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to all your components, the best shot is to write a simple method that would disable everything (more or less like a state machine).

If you don't have a reference to all of them (like a GUI that uses reflection) you will need to get a root panel and iterate over it finding every component and disabling it.

Take a look at the Jemmy tool that is used to test Netbeans, they have a GUIBrowser that can give you an idea.

Comment: The only problem I have with this is it's impossible to restore the previous state.  What if some components were already disabled?

Answer (score 0):

That makes use of `JXLayer` and [JHLabs filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html), basically, it creates a custom frame that wraps the `JRootPane` in a `JXLayer`, which allows you to "disable" the entire frame...

[image: On][image: off]

```
import com.jhlabs.image.BlurFilter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.jxlayer.JXLayer;
import org.jdesktop.jxlayer.plaf.effect.BufferedImageOpEffect;
import org.jdesktop.jxlayer.plaf.ext.LockableUI;

public class EnabledFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EnabledFrame();
    }

    public EnabledFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final LayeredFrame frame = new LayeredFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu mFile = new JMenu("File");
                mFile.add("Exit");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                mb.add(mFile);

                JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                });

                frame.add(btn);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LayeredFrame extends JFrame {

        private BlurableLockedUI lockUI;
        private JXLayer<JRootPane> rootLayer;

        public LayeredFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
            super(title);
        }

        @Override
        protected void setRootPane(JRootPane root) {
            if (rootLayer != null) {
                remove(rootLayer);
            }
            super.setRootPane(root);
            JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();
            rootLayer = new JXLayer<>(root);
            rootLayer.setUI(getLockUI());
            add(rootLayer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        protected BlurableLockedUI getLockUI() {
            if (lockUI == null) {
                lockUI = new BlurableLockedUI();
            }
            return lockUI;
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
            getLockUI().setLocked(!b);
            super.setEnabled(b);
        }

    }

    public class BlurableLockedUI extends LockableUI {

        public BlurableLockedUI() {
            super(new BufferedImageOpEffect(new BlurFilter()));
        }

        public void repaint() {
            setDirty(true);
        }

        public void invalidate() {
            setDirty(true);
        }

        public void revalidate() {
            setDirty(true);
        }

    }

}
```