# Disabling everything while swingworker is working?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have searched the net and can't find the specific thing that would help me out. I have my Swing Worker class doing some work in the background, while that is happening i would like to disable everything on my UI.

I don't want to go from one button to the next (Jlist, Jtable) etc and disabling everything. is there an easier way; Like drawing something on top of my UI and then removing it when Swing Worker is done? can somebody show me how to do something like that. Or what would be your suggestion.

I already know how to get a notice when Swing Worker is done. just looking for the best way to disable everything.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324918/how-to-disable-all-components-in-a-jpanel/19328368#19328368) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169662/how-would-i-disable-a-text-box/12169692#12169692) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799814/how-to-disable-enable-jframe-component-when-jinternalframe-isvisible-inside-jfra/20813257#20813257) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799451/java-blocking-focus-from-jcomponent/19801009#19801009)

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to parse your JFrame.getChildren() in a recursive manner.

But you could also use a GlassPane- see [Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)